# Strange Character In Tempurture Reading

Tags: esp32

Can anyone identify this character?
[image]

Comment: Thats an A with a circumflex. Does that answer your question? If you want to know why it is there you need to provide way more information, including your code

Comment: Everything @chrisl said. Plus you should know that there are multiple, at least two, Unicode sequences that will generate that same representation.

Answer (score 3):

The degree sign (°) is Unicode character U+00B0 (i.e. code point 0xb0).
In UTF-8, it is encoded as the two-byte sequence 0xc2 0xb0. Your browser
is not aware that the page is encoded as UTF-8, and for some reason it
believed it is ISO-8859-1. This two-byte sequence, interpreted as
ISO-8859-1, represents the two characters “Â” and “°”.

The simplest solution might be to add

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

at the top of the `<head>` element of the Web page.

Comment: … or use the `&deg;` html entity.

Comment: OUTSTANDING!
Edgar's single line suggestion solved the problem! The ESP32 page looks perfect now.

Comment: @RachelR And Grimaldi's suggestion is the Only Right<TM> solution. ;-) Please mark the answer you see fit best as "accepted". You might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: @thebusybee: Do you mean there is something Wrong™ in encoding Web pages in UTF-8?

Comment: It depends. ;-) Say you want to support the most systems, not only Win, Mac, and Linux, then you need to assume that not all of them know UTF-8. As someone living in a country with non-ASCII characters in written language, one of the more annoying problems is the lack of encoding such characters as HTML entities. Anyway, it's alright, if you accept rare cases of "strange characters".

Comment: @thebusybee: You know of a Web browser that understands `&deg;` but not `°` written in UTF-8? Is that Mosaic, or some other retro-computing thing? It's 2023 now. UTF-8 has been around for 30 years, and is the undisputed de facto standard encoding of the Web over the whole planet. I firmly believe it's time to move on and leave pre-UTF-8 browsers to computer history museums.

Comment: Oh, it's not about web servers, but web browsers. And (without having tried) there are a lot of old and small computers still in use that cannot run a full-fledged browser like Firefox or Chromium. For example, I have an old (20+ years) notebook running Void Linux just fine on the work bench. It is perfect for most development tasks, but not for "modern" web surfing. Not to speak of hobbyists still working with their ZX81. :-D Yes, there are such, but granted, their number is small.

Comment: And the OP's use case is apparently something like environment values provided by a web server, well in the realm of IoT. To use limited devices as "display" is quite common with this. -- Final line: If a standard is more compatible, even old, why should one use a less compatible standard, just because it is newer? Both work with modern browsers. But only the old one works with limited browsers.

Comment: @thebusybee: I do understand it's about browsers. It would be interesting to test `&deg;` vs. `°` on your old notebook. What browser does it run? Note that parsing UTF-8 requires less computing resources than parsing named references. IMO, the value of UTF-8 lies in the readability of the source, which I do value a lot.

Comment: Let us save the time, I cannot afford to investigate this detail. I just made a general remark targeting the usage of old standards compared to new standards just because of its broader support . It does not make your answer wrong, and I suggested to accept it.

Comment: @thebusybee: Only tangentially related to this discussion... I just stumbled on [WebOne](https://github.com/atauenis/webone), a HTTP proxy that makes old browsers usable in the modern Web. Looks like a cool project, and I thought it may be of interest to you.